# Angular: Controller is undefined when adding a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the following error when adding a directive to my site:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined
```

The error only occurs when I include the welcome-directive (welcome.js) in my site. If the import is removed the controller works.

Body of my index.html

```
<body ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <welcome></welcome>
  </div>

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
  <!-- Without this line the controller works -->
  <script src="js/directives/welcome.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('my-app', []);
})();
```

mainController.js

```
angular.module('my-app', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('Controller working');
  }]);
```

welcome.js

```
angular.module('my-app', [])
  .directive("welcome", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div>Test test.</div>"
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are redefining the module. Define module only once.

when used as `angular.module('my-app', [])` it defined the module this should be used only once. When you want retrieve it. then use `angular.module('my-app')`

*Use*

```
angular.module('my-app')  //Notice remove []
  .directive("welcome", function() {
  });
```

Comment: in both the controller and the directive definitions.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Do I always leave out the brackets when I have no dependencies?

Comment: @fwind, You need to define Module only once in entire application with whatever dependencies you have on module level.

Answer (score 3):

passing a 2nd argument like this `angular.module('my-app', [])` creates a new module, use it only once.

To retrive a module use `var module = angular.module('my-app')` and use `module.controller(...` or `module.directive(....` etc.,